# Drawing lines over buttons in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm developing a Tic Tac Toe game in order to use it in another project of mine and I'm having problems trying to add some final touches to the game. My game is made using 9 buttons and the problem is that I don't know how to draw lines over the buttons when one of the players win. I've managed to create the lines exactly where I want them to be located, but they are always drawn under the buttons and so can't be seen.

I've already tried adding frames over the buttons, what partially worked, but the problem is that it can't be used when the player wins diagonally.

Here's my code:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
root.geometry("250x250")
root.config(bg="white")

canvas = Canvas(root, height=150, width=150, bg="black", highlightthickness=0)
canvas.place(x=50, y=50)

frames = [[]]
buttons = [[]]
```

This is the function which creates the buttons in the canvas:

```
def generategame():

  for m in range(3):

    frames.append([])
    buttons.append([])

    for n in range(3):

        frames[m].append(Frame(canvas, width=48, height=48))
        frames[m][n].propagate(0)
        frames[m][n].place(x=(n*51), y=(m*51))

        buttons[m].append(Button(frames[m][n], text="", command=lambda i=m, j=n: turn(i, j)))
        buttons[m][n].config(bg="white", bd=0)
        buttons[m][n].pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

And it's the piece of code that checks if a player has won:

```
def checkwin(winner):

  if buttons[0][0]["text"] == buttons[0][1]["text"] == buttons[0][2]["text"] != "":
    print(winner + " WINS")

  if buttons[1][0]["text"] == buttons[1][1]["text"] == buttons[1][2]["text"] != "":
    print(winner + " WINS")

  if buttons[2][0]["text"] == buttons[2][1]["text"] == buttons[2][2]["text"] != "":
    print(winner + " WINS")

  if buttons[0][0]["text"] == buttons[1][0]["text"] == buttons[2][0]["text"] != "":
    print(winner + " WINS")

  if buttons[0][1]["text"] == buttons[1][1]["text"] == buttons[2][1]["text"] != "":
    print(winner + " WINS")

  if buttons[0][2]["text"] == buttons[1][2]["text"] == buttons[2][2]["text"] != "":
    print(winner + " WINS")

  if buttons[0][0]["text"] == buttons[1][1]["text"] == buttons[2][2]["text"] != "":
    print(winner + " WINS")

  if buttons[0][2]["text"] == buttons[1][1]["text"] == buttons[2][0]["text"] != "":
    print(winner + " WINS")
```

I've tried doing something like this, but it draws the line under the buttons:

```
if buttons[0][0]["text"] == buttons[0][1]["text"] == buttons[0][2]["text"] != "":
    canvas.create_line(0, 25, 150, 25)
    print(winner + " WINS")
```

The game is working perfectly but I just can't add this final touch. Am I doing something wrong or it's impossible to do this in tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot draw canvas objects on top of widgets that have been created on a canvas, or which have been added on top of a canvas with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.

From the canonical tcl/tk documentation on [window items](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M151):

> Note: due to restrictions in the ways that windows are managed, it is not possible to draw other graphical items (such as lines and images) on top of window items. A window item always obscures any graphics that overlap it, regardless of their order in the display list.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to heightlight the winning line is by changing the foreground and background colours or using a asterisk * symbol with large font size of the winning line :)

Since tkinter doesn't support drawing line over widget